# Can't log in superset: Unable to load SQLAlchemy dialect <class 'superset.extensions.metadb.SupersetAPSWDialect'>: No module named 'google'

Tags: sqlalchemy, module, apache-superset

I am deploying Superset with Dokku. After deploying the app, I've created admin user, but I can't log in. Here is the login log:

`2023-10-06T19:15:35.971486267Z app[web.1]: 2023-10-06 19:15:35,971:INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [06/Oct/2023 19:15:35] "GET /health HTTP/1.1" 200 - 2023-10-06T19:15:41.132003330Z app[web.1]: 2023-10-06 19:15:41,131:INFO:werkzeug:192.168.122.1 - - [06/Oct/2023 19:15:41] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - 2023-10-06T19:15:41.172697608Z app[web.1]: 2023-10-06 19:15:41,172:INFO:werkzeug:192.168.122.1 - - [06/Oct/2023 19:15:41] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 - 2023-10-06T19:15:41.179765862Z app[web.1]: 2023-10-06 19:15:41,179:WARNING:root:Class 'werkzeug.local.LocalProxy' is not mapped 2023-10-06T19:15:41.199842954Z app[web.1]: 2023-10-06 19:15:41,199:INFO:werkzeug:192.168.122.1 - - [06/Oct/2023 19:15:41] "GET /superset/welcome/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - 2023-10-06T19:15:41.228463214Z app[web.1]: Unable to load SQLAlchemy dialect <class 'superset.extensions.metadb.SupersetAPSWDialect'>: No module named 'google' 2023-10-06T19:15:41.228493450Z app[web.1]: 2023-10-06 19:15:41,228:WARNING:superset.db_engine_specs:Unable to load SQLAlchemy dialect <class 'superset.extensions.metadb.SupersetAPSWDialect'>: No module named 'google'` 
I've tried to install the google module (IDK why it's required), but no success at all. Can you help me?

Tried to install the google module (pip install google in Dockerfile).

Comment: What does your `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` look like?